# Codeigniter and Raw PHP in one project sharing one database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am in the process of creating a booking portal for salons. My problem is that salon owner admin panel project is created in raw PHP, but salon directory website and customer dashboards are created in Codeigniter framework. Is it possible to merge these two projects together and use some tables from raw PHP project database in Codeigniter project. This is my first project and I'm confused. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: The database isn't connected to the apps. It's the apps that connects to the database. You can have 100 (arbitrary number) apps connecting to the same database.

Comment: just edit the details in `database.php` (codeigniter) to point to your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a brand new application project in Codeigniter. As long as there is a database, you can create any application in multiple languages and frameworks. I would suggest having a look at Laravel as Codeigniter is quite dated and wouldn't allow you to scale easily as things grow complex.